# Unable to type using my keyboard in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6.0.1

I am using *Xcode 6.0.1*, I unable to type text using my apple wireless keyboard on the simulator.
 
Previously I have used *Xcode 5.1.1* in that it works fine.

I am finding more difficulty type the text without using my keyboard on iOS simulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you run your app, opens automatically  the iOS Simulator, so .. you select, from the menu, Hardware>Keyboard>Connect Hardware Keyboard

it worked for me (:

Answer (score 2):

At finally  solved that problem with the help of @mab answer. Open the iOS simulator Then Go to Hardware>Keyboard and select the Connect Hardware Keyboard option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your Simulator **Hardware** → **Keyboard** → **Connect Hardware Keyboard** (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>) doesn't work, then simply close your Simulator application (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>) and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

You likely hit shift-cmd-k or otherwise disconnected your hardware keyboard.  Check the Hardware->Keyboard menu.

Comment: Well check the Hardware -> Keyboard menu.  The keyboard works fine for me.